# Class per single attribute

Tags: html, css

I'm finding in several places the use of a single class for a single css attribute. The result is something like this:

```
 <header>
    <h1 class="secondary-text-colour heading-large">@Messages("xxx")</h1>
    <span class="secondary-text-colour heading-small">@Messages("xxx")</span>
 </header>
```

We can see how `heading-large` is only used for setting the font size or `primary-text-colour` is used to set the colour of the font.

My idea of good design would be something like:

```
  <header>
    <h1 class="header-main">@Messages("xxx")</h1>
    <span class="header-subtitle">@Messages("xxx")</span>
  </header>
```

In this second scenario you define a class for your element and you define the style with the css.

I sincerely think that this is how css and classes should be used but I need formal explanation to defend it in front of other team members. Can anyone give me any feedback on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example... You have a very big project whith a design that requires many boxes with a `box-shadow`.

If You have to copy and paste:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
```

for every container class that is going to have the shadow you are adding hundreds of unnecesary lines to your css sheet. But if you just add a single class like:

```
.shadow {
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

You just need to add the class to whatever container needs the shadow in the html.

Faster, cleaner, easier.

Comment: Can you check my update and let me know if you still think the same?

Comment: Absolutely. You are missunderstanding the use of many classes with how to name correctly the class. In your case the line should look like: <h1 class="header-main shadow corporate-color-bg">@Messages("xxx")</h1> where you add whatever exclusive css atributes to "header-main" like font-size, position, etc... and you add common classes like shadow-box and the web main color as background. Get it?

Comment: and finally, imagin you have to open a project to make some changes after a few years inactivity (happens often). You will never remember what "header-main" does to your container, but you will inmediately know what "shadow" and "corporate-color-bg" does. Specially if you are a front-end developer and you use the same type of nomenclature on all your projects. Reading the html code is MUCH easier.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly how classes should be used. They provide a semantic layer of abstraction to the reader of the HTML. I would encourage you to read this book about [SMACSS](https://smacss.com/) it provides  a great understanding of CSS architecture in general.

EDIT

Your idea is less modular than the original approach, see the SMACSS book for more information on this topic. Maybe you would like to change the color of this new headline, but still have the same font as in all other headlines. If you have one selector for each you would have to change both places if the font changes later. This gets even harder if you have large stylesheets and searching each position in the styles which would be needed is much harder than writing two classes in fist place.

Comment: Can you check my update and let me know if you still think the same?